# Analyzing time series data stored in an image collection with GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series

I have a time series of an index called "slope" from 2002 to 2022 stored in a GEE Image Collection, one image per year.

I am analyzing only the negative values of the index. From that time series, I want to extract some information, for instance:

- How long is the most extended period with consecutive negative values?
- When does this period start?

The following picture shows what the ImageColleciton looks like: there are 21 images, each image with one band called "slope," and in the image properties I have stored the year

[image: ImageCollection]

Does anyone know how I can start tackling this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many questions here. The first one is comparing two consecutive images and storing a value if both meet that condition. You can map over a list of indices to do that. For example:

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-71.10334557364457, -30.294295498332154])
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2");

var col = imageCollection.filterBounds(geometry).toList(21);

var n = ee.List.sequence(0,19);

var threshold = 2000;

function compare(i){
  var imgA = ee.Image(col.get(i));
  var imgB = ee.Image(col.get(ee.Number(1).add(i)));
  return imgA.select('NDVI').lt(threshold).and(imgB.select('NDVI').lt(threshold));
}

var result = ee.ImageCollection(n.map(compare).flatten());
```

`result` is a binary image collection with 1 if both meet the condition. That's the first step